# App.config in WCF Library and its Windows Service Host

Tags: wcf, service, app-config

I have two Services called TemplateService, TemplateReportService (both defined in one WCF Service Library) to be exposed to the client application.

And, I am trying to host these services under Windows Service.

Can anyone please guide me if App.config in Windows Service will be same as the one in WCF Library?

Here is my app.config in WCF Library:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" />
  </system.web>

  <system.serviceModel>     
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="ReportingComponentLibrary.TemplateServiceBehavior"
        name="ReportingComponentLibrary.TemplateService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="ReportingComponentLibrary.ITemplateService" >
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" ></endpoint>
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8080/ReportingComponentLibrary/TemplateService/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>

      <service behaviorConfiguration="ReportingComponentLibrary.TemplateServiceBehavior"
        name="ReportingComponentLibrary.TemplateReportService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="ReportingComponentLibrary.ITemplateReportService" >
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8080/ReportingComponentLibrary/TemplateReportService/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>

    </services>

    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ReportingComponentLibrary.TemplateServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="True" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

So, the App.config in my Windows Service(Where I am hosting above two services)
will be same as above or there are only some particular sections that I need to move.

Please guide.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, remove the  as we talked about in your other question. Second libraries don't have their own .config files and there is no (built in) way to import certain configuration sections in .NET. So you must consolidate the configuration settings for each library into the single app.config of the Windows service.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The mistake I was doing was to copy app.config from WCF Library to Windows Service Installation folder. Whereas I just had to make changes in <ServiceName>.exe.config found in Windows Service Installation folder.